# How do I combine two MySQL databases from different points in time?

Tags: mysql, linux

I recently switch to a new hosting provider for my application. My employees used the old site until the new site went live, however, the database backup from the old site was taken two days before the new site went live. So in the midst of transferring, records were being entered into the old site database while the new site had no existence of them (hence my two day time lag). How do I merge the two databases to reflect the changes?

A couple of things to note are the primary keys might be duplicated for some tables and there are only timestamps on a few tables as well. I would do a 'diff' or something of the sort, but the tables are dumped in different formats.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is something where you'll need to actually understand your database schema. You'll need to create a program that can look at both versions of the database, identify which records are shared, which are not, and which have conflicting primary keys (vs ones which were updated with the same keys). It then needs to copy over changes, possibly replacing the value of primary keys (including the values in other rows that refer to the row being renumbered!) This isn't easy, and it's not an exact science - you'll be writing heuristics, and expect to do some manual repairs as well.

Next time shut that database down when you grab the final backup :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create any additional programs. All what you need, to setup replications from the old DB to the new one.
All your data from the old DB will automatically transfer to the new DB. At this period you should use you old DB as the main data source. And as soon as all data will be copied to the new location, you'll need just brake replica connection and change the DB address in your code (or DNS pointer) to the new one.

```
1.       oldDB ===> replication ==> newDB
    R/W operations

2.       oldDB ==/= brake ==/=      newDB
                               R/W operations
```

[MySQL Doc: 15.1.1. How to Set Up Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)